# Laravel 5.7 Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I'm a newbie and learning laravel 5.7. Registration is done but having problem Authenticating during login, Auth::attempt always returns false

I tried using `Hash::check('plain-text','Hashed password)` and it returns true
The problem is `Auth::attempt` always returns false

UserController.php:

```
// Registration code
public function register(Request $request){
       $request->validate([
            'firstName' => 'required',
            'lastName' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required|min:3',
            'password' => 'min:6|required_with:confirm_password|same:confirm_password',
            'confirm_password' => 'min:6'
        ]);

        Users::create([
            'firstName' => request('firstName'),
            'lastName' => request('lastName'),
            'username' => request('username'),
            'password' => Hash::make(request('password'))
        ]);
        notify()->success('Registered Successfully!');
        return redirect('/');

    }

// Login code
public function login(Request $request){

//      This returns true
//        if(Hash::check('123456','$2y$10$BrOg1JtnX7hAX05gbT9p0OZFQB9mFKtcz0m5Ks2rSHIN//B20dODgA.')){
//            return 'OK';
//        }


        $credentials = request([
            'username',
            'password'
        ]);


// Always returns false
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            notify()->success('Welcome!');
            return back();

        }else{
            notify()->warning('Credentials not found!');
            return back();
        }




    }
```

Users.php:

```
//Model
class Users extends Model 
{
    //
    protected $guarded = [];


}
```

auth.php:

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Users::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

migrations:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('firstName');
            $table->string('lastName');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

login.blade.php:

```
<form action="/" method="post" autocomplete="on">
                        @csrf
                        <h1>Log in</h1>
                        <p>
                            <label for="Username"  data-icon="u"> Username</label>
                            <input id="Username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder=""/>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="Password"  data-icon="p"> Password </label>
                            <input id="Password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder=""/>
                        </p>
                        <p class="login button">
                            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                        </p>
                        <p class="change_link">
                            Not a member yet ?
                            <a href="/register" class="to_register">Join us</a>
                        </p>
                    </form>
```

*NOTE*

I'm positive that I am getting the correct inputs

```
// Returns correct information
{
"username": "yeah",
"password": "123456"
}
```

Comment: You have Authentication functionality out of the box. You don't need to rewrite them :) Check inside `App\Http\Controllers\Auth;`, let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thanks, I will check on this ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to try to rewrite the Login functionality (neither Register) as these comes out of the box in Laravel. What you need to do is:

First in your `login.blade.php`

```
<form action="/login" method="post" autocomplete="on">
```

Then in your `web.php`

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

Now go to your `App\Http\Auth\LoginController`

```
// Add this function to overwrite default email to username
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Comment: I've applied what you said, after login it just redirects to the login page,
I'm not sure if the authentication was successful, is there anyway to know if it was success or failed? like console.log() ^^

Comment: `dd(Auth::user())` - `dd()` is like `console.log` in Laravel. I'd say try to do some learning before moving forward :)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses `email` by default to authorize the user, so try overriding the field which you use in your `LoginController` add this:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry i'm a bit new, Should I put this at the UserController.php or at the User.php(Model)?

Comment: @CaTzNeko you can just re-use the default auth functionality.